# Python confusing arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pymysql, pandasql

Sometimes pythons dynamic typing system is confusing to understand why some things work. For example:

- Why does pandas.read_sql() **accept and work as intended** on a pymysql.Connection object as returned from pymysql.connect()? **Note** that nowhere in pandas documentation do they note that a pymysql.Connection object is accepted.

I'm looking for some clarification on the above question **and** some advice on how to generalise towards similar situations.

Comment: What you do mean, "why"? You can pass any value you want, as long as it can be used in the way the function tries to use it.

Comment: @chepner see edit

Comment: This is a question better suited for the users at [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) than SO. There is not an issue with the code as far as I can see, but rather why the developers chose to do something the way they did.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh No, it relates to python, I simply gave an example that can be generalized.

Comment: The things `pandas.read_sql` does internally just happen to work for a `pymysql.Connection` instance, apparently. You might as well ask why "alternately press left and right pedals" makes both bikes and cars go forward even though the procedure was only designed for bikes. It's not a good idea to do that with a car, or to use `pandas.read_sql` with a `pymysql.Connection`.

Comment: [First they do note that pymysql is accepted](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.0/pandas/io/sql.py#L336-L439). There is more to documentation than just words and often viewing source code can be valuable. Second it is that way because python is a dynamically typed language. This really is off topic as a SO question.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh: I don't see anything about pymysql in what you linked.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh: You have to actually *use* SQLAlchemy, passing a SQLAlchemy connectable, for that to apply.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh But what does that mean "to use any DB"? It doesn't relate to any class or specific python object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_sql` is documented as taking a `Connectable` object. Strictly speaking, that means it would be an instance of `SqlAlchemy.engine.Connectable` or a subclass thereof, but the only thing that is important is that it *behave* like such an instance. Roughly speaking, you can pass anything that's "like" a `Connectable`, in that, for example, tt provides a `connect` method that takes the same kinds of arguments as `sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable.connect`.

In other words, it's not the exact type that matters, but the *interface* to the type you pass. Python refers to this as *duck typing*: if an object looks like a duck and acts like a duck, it can be used by something that requires a duck, even if it's not, actually, a duck.

Comment: Sometimes, the interface is all that matters, but unless it's explicitly documented that the interface is all that matters, the more common case is that the code expects specific types but isn't designed to check that precondition. Relying on undocumented support for other types can quickly fall apart when a new library version changes things a little and triggers different implicit checks.

Comment: E.g., a new version tries to perform `==` comparisons, which usually involve a type check, or a new version tries to call the unbound `list.index` method on something that was assumed to be a list, triggering the `self` type check for unbound C methods.